# Docker Ruby 2.2.3 simply Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

I'm following [the tutorial "Running a Rails Development Environment in Docker"](https://blog.codeship.com/running-rails-development-environment-docker/), but I'm stuck in the 1 point, when I type:

```
docker build -t demo .
```

I'm in the "new rails" folder called `demo` (the main directory of a new Rails app).

I'm using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.2 
MAINTAINER marko@codeship.com

# Install apt based dependencies required to run Rails as 
# well as RubyGems. As the Ruby image itself is based on a 
# Debian image, we use apt-get to install those.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \ 
  build-essential \ 
  nodejs

# Configure the main working directory. This is the base 
# directory used in any further RUN, COPY, and ENTRYPOINT 
# commands.
RUN mkdir -p /app 
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the Gemfile as well as the Gemfile.lock and install 
# the RubyGems. This is a separate step so the dependencies 
# will be cached unless changes to one of those two files 
# are made.
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./ 
RUN gem install bundler && bundle install --jobs 20 --retry 5

# Copy the main application.
COPY . ./

# Expose port 3000 to the Docker host, so we can access it 
# from the outside.
EXPOSE 3000

# The main command to run when the container starts. Also 
# tell the Rails dev server to bind to all interfaces by 
# default.
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

I receive this error:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 100.4 kB
Step 1 : FROM ruby:2.2.3
 ---> a930a50e60f8
Step 2 : MAINTAINER Myself
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3c4ae5eefe92
Step 3 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y   build-essential   nodejs
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 65ecc91ac6be
Step 4 : RUN mkdir -p /dev
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1ce330a396b6
Step 5 : WORKDIR /dev
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9b5d130285cb
Step 6 : COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 14c639732ae7
Step 7 : RUN gem install bundler && bundle install --jobs 20 --retry 5
 ---> Running in 672397cecd6d
Successfully installed bundler-1.10.6
1 gem installed
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
users on this machine.
Could not locate Gemfile
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
The command '/bin/sh -c gem install bundler && bundle install --jobs 20 --retry 5' returned a non-zero code: 10
```

Why I got this error and I can't build the container?

Comment: Anyone can help with this problem?

Comment: As far as I see, bundler is installed successfully, but a message `Could not locate Gemfile` means there is no Gemfile in working directory. Please  check again is there this file in you project?

Comment: might help https://shivab.com/blog/docker/2019/01/15/dockerization-of-rails-6-app/

Answer (score 0):

Your `Dockerfile` said

```
RUN mkdir -p /app 
WORKDIR /app
```

But the logs say:

```
Step 4 : RUN mkdir -p /dev
---> Using cache
---> 1ce330a396b6
Step 5 : WORKDIR /dev
```

What is correct? `/dev` or `/app`?